# SQLite android google map marker issue

Tags: android, sqlite, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need to make a map with onClick marker creation. Markers are saved in db and when the marker is clicked, info must be shown in another activity. I get null pointer exception with no reason at all...This is what i have so far:
This is my main activity:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,OnMapClickListener,OnMarkerClickListener {

private GoogleMap mMap;
public LatLng markerLatLng;
public JSONArray js;
public LatLng latLng;
public Location location;
public DbActions DbActions;
public List<Markers> markersList;
public Markers readyMarker;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}



@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)throws SecurityException {

    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    double lat = location.getLatitude();
    double lon = location.getLongitude();
    latLng = new LatLng(lat, lon);
    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.setOnMapClickListener(this);
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(true);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(16));
    mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);
    markersList = new ArrayList<>();


}
@Override
public void onPause() {

    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();


}

@Override
public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {

    js = null;
    markerLatLng = latLng;
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(markerLatLng).title("Click me").draggable(true));
    getAddress(latLng);

}

public void getAddress(LatLng latLng)  {
    URL url = null;
    try {
        url = new URL("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="+latLng.latitude+","+latLng.longitude+"&key=AIzaSyDE3_JFqocq7yObLvLayj0xMs3YRiVhiJI");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Async async =new Async();
    async.execute(url);

}
@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
    DbActions = new DbActions(getApplicationContext(), null, null, 1);
    Markers markerFromDB = DbActions.getOneMarker(readyMarker.get_lat(),readyMarker.get_lng());
    MarkerInfo markerInfo =new MarkerInfo();
    String address = markerFromDB.get_address();
    String locat = markerFromDB.get_lat()+","+markerFromDB.get_lng();
    markerInfo.addressView.setText(address);
    markerInfo.addressView.setText(locat);
    Intent intent = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, com.example.fixxxer.mapapplication.MarkerInfo.class);
    startActivity(intent);

    return false;
}
public class Async extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, JSONArray> {
    public JSONArray jsonArray;
    String country;
    public JSONObject jsFirstAddress;

    @Override
    protected JSONArray doInBackground(URL... params) {
        BufferedReader reader;
        InputStream is;
        try {

            StringBuilder responseBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) params[0].openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.connect();
            is = conn.getInputStream();
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            for (String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null; ) {
                responseBuilder.append(line).append("\n");
            }
            JSONObject jObj= new JSONObject(responseBuilder.toString());
            jsonArray = jObj.getJSONArray("results");
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return jsonArray;

    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray jsonArrayResponse) {
        js = jsonArrayResponse;
        jsFirstAddress = null;
        JSONArray jsCountry;
        country = "";
        try {
            if (js != null) {
                jsFirstAddress = js.getJSONObject(0);
                if (jsFirstAddress != null) {
                    jsCountry = jsFirstAddress.getJSONArray("address_components");
                    JSONObject jsComponents;
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsCountry.length(); i++) {
                        jsComponents = jsCountry.getJSONObject(i);
                        if (jsComponents.getString("types").contains("country")) {
                            country = jsComponents.getString("long_name");
                        }
                    }
                    readyMarker = new Markers(jsFirstAddress.getString("formatted_address"), country, markerLatLng.latitude, markerLatLng.longitude, "image");

                }

            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        DbActions = new DbActions(getApplicationContext(), null, null, 1);
        DbActions.addMarker(readyMarker);

    }
}
```

This is DBHelper class:

```
public class DbActions extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "locations.db";
public static final String TABLE_LOCATIONS = "locations";

public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
public static final String COLUMN_ADDRESS = "address";
public static final String COLUMN_COUNTRY = "country";
public static final String COLUMN_LAT = "lat";
public static final String COLUMN_LNG = "lng";
public static final String COLUMN_IMAGE = "image";


public DbActions(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION);
}


@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String query = "CREATE TABLE " +
            TABLE_LOCATIONS + "(" +
            COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            COLUMN_ADDRESS + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_COUNTRY + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_LAT + " REAL, " +
            COLUMN_LNG + " REAL, " +
            COLUMN_IMAGE + " TEXT " +
            ");";

    db.execSQL(query);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_LOCATIONS);
    onCreate(db);
}

public void addMarker(Markers marker) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_ADDRESS, marker.get_address());
    values.put(COLUMN_COUNTRY, marker.get_country());
    values.put(COLUMN_LAT, marker.get_lat());
    values.put(COLUMN_LNG, marker.get_lng());
    values.put(COLUMN_IMAGE, marker.get_image());
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    db.insert(TABLE_LOCATIONS, null, values);
    db.close();
}

public void deleteMarker(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_LOCATIONS + " WHERE " + COLUMN_ID + "=\"" + id + "\";");
}

public List<Markers> getExistingMarkers() {
    ArrayList<Markers> list = new ArrayList<>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_LOCATIONS;
    Cursor curs = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    curs.moveToFirst();
    while (!curs.isAfterLast()) {

        Markers marker = new Markers(
                curs.getString(1),
                curs.getString(2),
                Double.parseDouble(curs.getString(3)),
                Double.parseDouble(curs.getString(4)),
                curs.getString(5));
        list.add(marker);
    }
    curs.close();
    return list;
}

public Markers getOneMarker(double lat,double lng) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM "+ TABLE_LOCATIONS+ " WHERE "+ COLUMN_LAT +"=?"+ " AND " +COLUMN_LNG+"=?";
    Cursor curs = db.rawQuery(query,new String[]{String.valueOf(lat),String.valueOf(lng)});
    if (curs != null)
        curs.moveToFirst();

    Markers marker = new Markers(Integer.parseInt(curs.getString(0)),
            curs.getString(1), curs.getString(2),Double.parseDouble(curs.getString(3)),Double.parseDouble(curs.getString(4)),curs.getString(5));
    return marker;
}
```

and the other activity that have to show the info for the marker from DB:

```
public class MarkerInfo extends AppCompatActivity {
public TextView addressView;
public TextView latLngView;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_marker_info);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    addressView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.addressText);
    latLngView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.latlngText);

}
```

i get the null pointer here:

```
    String address = markerFromDB.get_address();//<----HERE!
    String locat = markerFromDB.get_lat()+","+markerFromDB.get_lng();
    markerInfo.addressView.setText(address);
    markerInfo.addressView.setText(locat);
```

Wierd thing is that when i Toast the address it comes out perfectly. But i can't toast the ID. I am really bad with SQLite so i think my mistake is somewhere there. Any ideas?
LOGCAT:

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException
11-14 16:27:28.703 16895-16895/com.example.fixxxer.mapapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.fixxxer.mapapplication.MapsActivity.onMarkerClick(MapsActivity.java:123)
```

This is line 123 :

```
  markerInfo.addressView.setText(address);
```

Comment: posted logcat update

Comment: You cant access another activity ui widgets in this way. Use intents to pass your strings into next activity and load them from there.